# table to updated after selection with uipicker

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipicker

An UIPicker shows up when I select a row in a table, so I can choose some things I want to be displayed on the same row.

How can I update the table once I finished with the uipicker? I used reloadData right after the call to the picker, but the code is executed before I do "Done" on the picker.

Some idea?

Thank u

Comment: try reload data on "Done" handle? You should provide more details on what are you doing - how you show UIPicker, what that "Done" is etc...

Comment: Done is just the button I use to confirm my selection in the uipicker. The UIPicker is defined in a class separated from the table, and I call it with [actionSheet showInView:self.view], [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];.

Answer (score 1):

USe the UIPicker delegate method `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`, and call `reloadData` from your delegate.

The object with your "done" action should be the delegate of the `UIPicker`, and implement the delegate method above.  In that delegate method call `reloadData`.  It will be called when the picker is done.

Comment: I've seen where the problem is, I could use didSelectRow or clickedButtonIndex, but what I need is how to call the reloadData from there, as the UIPicker is defined in a different class from the table.

thank u

Comment: Maybe the best question would be: How do I call reloadData from my UIPicker class? (which is outside the tableview controller I want to update).

The easy way is joining the two classes.

Comment: You do that by implementing the delegate method.  Really.